# how to place last component of a jPanel on the right edge, even if the panel has a flowLayout Left

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

**I have in my code :**

a jPanel with LEFT FlowLayout. 
It contains various components. see img:

[image: current tool output]

**what i'm trying to implement:** 
I'm trying to stick last component on the right edge of its panel container. See img:

[image: desidered tool output]

**i tried:**

to add a Box.createHorizontalGlue  before my last component, but it doesn't work as expected.

**The Code:**

Code has been created on purpose for the question and mirrors the original code logic:

```
public class TheMotherPuckerGlue {
    public static void main(String [] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 90);
        frame.setTitle("myCode");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel motherPucker = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.red);

        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
        panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));

        motherPucker.add(panel1);
        motherPucker.add(panel2);
//        motherPucker.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        motherPucker.add(panel3);
        motherPucker.setBackground(Color.white);

        frame.add(motherPucker,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Thank for any suggestion you'll leave! :D

Comment: *"how to place last component of a jPanel on the right edge, even if the panel has a flowLayout Left"* Use more than one layout.  E.G. put the yellow and green buttons into a flow layout, add that flow layout to the center of a panel with border layout, then add the red button to the line end of the border layout.

Comment: Is there any explaination about why the horizontalGlue behavior is different from the one described on the API? Thanks for your solution but there are tons of way to do it, and i am looking for a clean one. I ll try using the  Box.Filler if the Glue doesn't work

Comment: *"Is there any explaination about why the horizontalGlue behavior is different from the one described on the API?"*  Probably because the panel is not using the layout that glue is meant to apply to..  *"Thanks for your solution but there are tons of way to do it, and i am looking for a clean one."*  0_o  I'll leave you to that quest, then.

Comment: I don't see why you should be rude, or answer like you're superior.

Comment: @Koop4, your last comment doesn't add anything to the discussion and frankly is completely unnecessary. You have been given the answer why the "glue" isn't working so you should be thanking the Andrew for the advice. If there is something you don't understand about the advice then you ask for clarification.

Comment: so it is for your and his last comment too, and well, let s keep spamming then.
In first place, i already  said  thanks in my question, don't tell me what to do if not required, i am not 12. Thank you. 
Latter, but not least, we are engineers, and it should be obvious that an answer should "answer" the question, I didn't asked for a workaround, i asked for a solution, and i would prefer to hear "there is no way" instead then read shit.

Comment: @Koop4, `i already said thanks in my question,` - thanks should be given when an answer is received so we know you read the suggestion and took the time to understand it. `it should be obvious that an answer should "answer" the question` - exactly and you were given the answer. The answer is to use the layout manager that Box.glue was designed to be used for.

Comment: `I didn't asked for a workaround, i asked for a solution` You were given a solution. A FlowLayout automatically leaves space between components. By using two panels you get this automatic spacing AND you get the gap on the left. If you use a BoxLayout you need to add the spacing yourself. See your next question on how you complain about using a strut manually. So you were give two choices on how to solve the problem and then you decide which is best in your situation. Sorry you don't understand how much help you were given. That is why a separate "thank you" is appropriate.