# How to draw a white rectangle at the bottom of a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

In my code i have:

A Gui with a `JScrolledPane` containing a Box which contains some `JPanel` (they could be refactor as `JComponent` if needed).

See Image 1 :

[image: example]

I am trying to:

Find the best way to add a white space between them.

I tried with the Box.createVerticalStruct, but it complicates the managment.
I don't want to add a new white panel to my object representing the coloredPanel too, so i googled  it and it seems to me that there are other 2 ways: using inset or overriding the paint method.

What do you think is the best way in my case?
in case you'd suggest to use the paintComponent method, how do i retrieve the bottom corner position to draw a white rectangle of a certain height?

The final results should be something like this:

[image]

Here is some code you can use to make some try (which has been written on purpose, so don't take too much care on good writing techniques):

```
public class TheMotherPuckerGlue2 {

    public static void main(String [] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setTitle("myCode");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JScrollPane myPane = new JScrollPane();
        myPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,200));
        myPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel viewPort = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        viewPort.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Box myBox = Box.createVerticalBox(); 
        myBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));

        viewPort.add(myBox,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        class ColoredPanel extends JPanel{
            public ColoredPanel(Color aColor){
                super.setBackground(aColor);
                super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,60));
            }

        }

        ColoredPanel panel1 = new ColoredPanel(Color.green);
        ColoredPanel panel2 = new ColoredPanel(Color.yellow);
        ColoredPanel panel3 = new ColoredPanel(Color.red);

        myBox.add(panel1);
        myBox.add(panel2);
        myBox.add(panel3);

        viewPort.add(myBox,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


        myPane.setViewportView(viewPort);

        frame.add(myPane);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
   }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: *"find the best way to add a white space between them. I tried with the `Box.createVerticalStruct`, but it complicates the managment. "*  Use a single column `GridLayout` with **layout padding** (look at the constructors for it).  Set the BG color of the `GridLayout` panel to `WHITE`.

Comment: I didn't mention that the colored panels shown can contain components. Do you think it could be different? Meanwhile i am checking GridLayout JavaTutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great way to do that by rewriting the paintComponent that way:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawWhiteSpace(g);
    drawBorder(g);
}
```

drawWhiteSpace method will draw a white rectangle which start at the bottom-left
corner -6 pixel, and go to the bottom rightcorner

```
private void drawWhiteSpace(Graphics g) {
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = this.getSize().height-6;
    int x2 = this.getSize().width;
    int y2 = this.getSize().height;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);     
}
```

however the border was not fine, so i had to remove it and to draw it
myself by drawing it from the top-left corner to the top-right corner of the white space

```
private void drawBorder(Graphics g) {
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int x2 = this.getSize().width-1;
    int y2 = this.getSize().height-6;
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
}
```

Comment: No need for custom painting. Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use a Swing Border. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html). For working examples.

Comment: Read it. Borders are not usefull. If you find they may  work i ll have the pleasure to read your code.

Comment: Of course Borders are usefull. You attempt to paint your own border. Like I said, don't reinvent the wheel. Just add a Border to the ColoredPanel. Actually I'll have the pleasure of reading your code that showed what you attempted. I gave you a link to the tutorial. Explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: I meant Borders are not useful in my case. I am here to ask how to draw a white area, not how Borders works.
By the way the solution i wrote above works well, and i ll be happy to know if there is another way with Borders, which i am not gonna test since i 've already tried unsucesfully.

Comment: Your question was: `Find the best way to add a white space between them.` This is easily done with a "white border" on the bottom of your panel so you don't have to do any custom painting. `By the way the solution i wrote above works well` - only because you don't know how to use Swing properly. Using a Border you can do it in a single line of code without doing any custom painting. It is always better to use the existing API than create your own. I already pointed your to the tutorial. All you need to do is look at the pictures to pick the appropriate Border to use.

Comment: Seems like i am talking with a kid... you're impressing me. Let's see if it will allow me to let you go away:
OH THANK YOU SIR, IT WORKS LIKE A HELL! YOU RE SO GREAT.
gtfu kiddo.

Comment: You are the one asking for help. You've been given help. You are the one ignoring advice you have been given on this and other postings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255891/how-to-place-last-component-of-a-jpanel-on-the-right-edge-even-if-the-panel-has. Programming is about logic. If you can't see the logic in my answers, well there is no much I can do.